# Modifing text in pl file with swi-prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the following file in prolog, **1111000011110000.pl** :

```
:- multifile firstname/1.
:- multifile surname/1.
:- multifile cardNumber/1.
:- multifile code/1.
:- multifile balance/1.

% firstname("Martin").
firstname([77, 97, 114, 116, 105, 110]).

% surname("Andersson").
surname([65, 110, 100, 101, 114, 115, 115, 111, 110]).

% cardNumber(card-number)
cardNumber(1111000011110000).

% code(code)
code(1337).

% balance(balance)
balance(3230000).
```

I want to create a predicate that takes an integer-input (for instance 0) and modifies the 1111000011110000.pl file so that the argument of the balance-predicate is changed to 0. For instance, after using the predicate I am supposed to modify the 1111000011110000.pl file to:

```
:- multifile firstname/1.
:- multifile surname/1.
:- multifile cardNumber/1.
:- multifile code/1.
:- multifile balance/1.

% firstname("Martin").
firstname([77, 97, 114, 116, 105, 110]).

% surname("Andersson").
surname([65, 110, 100, 101, 114, 115, 115, 111, 110]).

% cardNumber(card-number)
cardNumber(1111000011110000).

% code(code)
code(1337).

% balance(balance)
balance(0).
```

Is this possible in prolog? :)

Comment: Look at this post, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857202/prolog-insert-modify-and-delete-facts-on-a-separated-database-text-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prolog insert, modify and delete facts on a separated database text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857202/prolog-insert-modify-and-delete-facts-on-a-separated-database-text-file)